# rtmp audio out of sync, http works fine

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

We have encoded and distributed videos for some years now, using FFMPEG to produce h.264/mp4 files that have been working great for us. We have been using HTML mode and fall-backed to flash for browsers that does not support it natively using flowplayer.

We use cloudfront to serve our files from a s3 bucket and have been using http progressive streaming.

Recently we started distribute the files in flashmode over rtmp instead, using a cloudfront streaming distribution pointing to the same amazon s3 bucket.

All good for some weeks, until yesterday when we notice a couple of files with audio sync issues in rtmp mode.
The same file have no sync problems in flash with direct url to file.

What can be the case?

Not working when streamed via RTMP, but file work with http streaming/progressive.
You see the sync issue 15 sec's into the video.
rtmp://s2xe2avk54qztf.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st/mp4:95fvOY255bdPspO3z6tEvGi3Em7/default.mp4
http://media.shootitlive.com/95fvOY255bdPspO3z6tEvGi3Em7/default.mp4

Another file that have no sync issue at all.
rtmp://s2xe2avk54qztf.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st/mp4:P4EuH2TZxfV6BvpupP6dxrrs7gD/default.mp4
http://media.shootitlive.com/P4EuH2TZxfV6BvpupP6dxrrs7gD/default.mp4

Both files have the same format for video and audio and have been encoded the exact same way with ffmpeg. It's not player related as we see the audio sync issue on several players and when playing stream in VLC.

Comment: Do you have this problem with RTMP when not using CloudFront?  It seems like you have done all the testing you can, and I see the same problem with VLC and your streams here.  I think this is a problem with their RTMP implementation somehow.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. How can I test the files using another RTMP provider in an easy way without setting up a Wowza or Flash Media server?

Comment: Setting up Wowza or something is what I would suggest.  Either that or open a support ticket with Amazon for CloudFront, as it seems this issue is squarely on their end, especially if the problem just began.

Comment: Thanks. Posted this question on the Amazon Cloudfront forum at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=144364 (if anyone else experiencing the same problem, answers might be there)